# If element doesn't exist, add to input field in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I am trying to add a hashtag to an input field. The problem is that when I add it, I can keep adding it. I am wondering of a way to check the input field and if the hashtag already exists, to not add it?

My javascript is:

```
$('.item').click(function(){

  var clonedTag = $("<div class='tag_clone' data-value=" + ($(this).attr('data-value')) + ">"+($(this).attr('data-value')) + "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='remove' tabindex='-1' title='Remove'>" + "×" + "</a>" + "</div>")

  $('.selectize-input.items.not-full').append(clonedTag)

})

$('.selectize-input.items.not-full').on('click', '.remove', function(e){
  $(this).parent('.tag_clone').remove()
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

So, if #example1 exists in the top input field, a user can not add it again (I'm using Selectize.js)

In the image below, I click the bottom input field to get a clone of the hashtag to the top input field.

[image]

Comment: Use `IndexOf` to find if `#` already exists

Comment: Protip: jQuery has a `data()` method